# font-family Work Sans not working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-fonts

Just accessed an app I haven't used for about a month and noticed the 'Work Sans' font wasn't working correctly in Google Chrome.

There are no error messages in Chrome developer tools console - the font just doesn't seem to be applied.

[jsFiddle demonstration link](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/v02L1beh/)

As viewed in Google Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit):

*update - still not working in Chrome 78.0.3904.70*

[image]

As viewed in Firefox Quantum 69.0.1 (64-bit):

[image]

**HTML**

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans|Roboto+Mono|Work+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<p class="testing1">
  Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
</p>


<p class="testing2">
  Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
</p>

<p class="testing3">
  Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
</p>
```

**CSS**

```css
.testing1 {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

.testing2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

.testing3 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

**Edit:**

In case anyone was wondering, the `@import` approach causes the same undesired behaviour, ie:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans|Roboto+Mono|Work+Sans:400,700&display=swap');
```

Answer (score -1):

I just entered with the same Google Chrome version than you and it works
and the link is right

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans|Roboto+Mono|Work+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

So is nothing about your app. Maybe was a Google Font temp issue.
Maybe you could also use Roboto Mono as a fallback if it breaks again before go for the sans-serif

```
.testing1 { font-family: 'Work Sans', 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif; }
```

Comment: I have just tested the jsFiddle link in recent chrome browser updates (versions 77.0.3865.120 and 78.0.3904.70), restarted and cleared browser cache and the problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

i tried this Method  and it worked for me

If you need a specific type of font(not usually common) to be displayed  in your chrome browser you need to find install in your system , which can be found free online at most cases .

Install the  .ttf  font type(in windows)   and change
the font settings in chrome to whichever font you want and it should work out  fine.[image: chrome settings]